# Symfony bundle Twig auto namespace not registered?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an "AppBundle" in my Symfony ( 3.4 ) Project and everthing is running fine in dev, but when deployed on production Server, I get following error:

```
There are no registered paths for namespace \"App\".
```

I use the twig namespace notation `@App\dir\templatefile` that should automatically be registered according to the docs. When I run `console debug:twig` I can see that there is no `@App` twig namespace registered.
Suprisingly, I have a second Bundle called `PackagingBundle`, and the namespace `Packaging` of that bundle is well registered.

How can this be ? Where are those namespaces defined ? Is there a file for that that I could modify ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this in the composer.json by setting autoloader path:

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

But for Bundles, in SF4 you have to set in the file config/bundles.php.

Comment: Mine is like this .. wrong ?:
 `"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
      "PackagingBundle\\": "src/PackagingBundle",
    },` ... it does work on dev AND for the PackagingBundle ? But I will give it a try ..

Comment: yes, there's really no namespace for 'App\', but for 'AppBundle\\', yes

Comment: But how come it works for Packaging and on dev ? Anyway, thank you, will give it a try ..

Comment: is this error about Twig? did you do a bin/console debug:twig ?

Comment: doa composer dump-autoload

Comment: I tried many things now in composer.json, but nothing does the trick !? Even when I put only `"": "src/"`, PackagingBundle is fine, but not AppBundle .... I really don't understand how one gets registered, but not the other one ?

Comment: ... and when I call routes that don't use Twig, even in the AppBundle, all works fine !? very strange ...

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I named the `views` folder in my AppBundle `Views` , with uppercase "V". I don't know why it worked on dev server and not on prod, that is just one of those mysteries.

Anyway, a stupid mistake that coast me a lot of time, so maybe this post can help someone save some time.